# C: Using pointer to access two dimensional array in function

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
int main() {

char test [2][4]= {"BbBa","CBAD"} ; /*two dimensional array */
char ch = 'A'; /* going to match this character */
int i=0;

int functionA (char test[]){
    char (*temp)[4] = test; /* if match to ch will print Yes */
    if (temp[2] == ch){
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else{
        printf("No.");
    }
}

for (i=0;i<2;i++){
functionA(test[i]);
}

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I want to compare the third element of BbBa and CBAD. Then result should be BbBa is "No." and CBAD is "Yes" because the third element of BbBa is "B" and CBAD is "A". However, both result are No.
Is there any difference of using pointer to access two dimensional array in a function?
Thank you.

Comment: Declaring functions inside functions is illegal in ANSI C

Comment: You should use pointers when you are working with dynamic arrays. Anyway, I would recommend you to place functions outside main or other functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*temp)[4] = test; /* if match to ch will print Yes */
```

This line in your context has very little sense - you as always can write function like so, without complicating too much *(You have unconsistent code style. Please note that I changed parameter name, to avoid confusion with global test)*:

```
int functionA (char toTest[], char ch){
    if (toTest[2] == ch){
        printf("Yes");
    } else{
        printf("No.");
    }
}
```

I would also pass char parameter to make function more flexible. This way, your loop is going to look like so:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
    functionA(test[i], 'A');
}
```

You can unroll it (small amount of iterations, wasting cycles):

```
functionA(test[0], 'A');
functionA(test[1], 'A');
```

After unrolling it even more, code looks like this:

```
if (test[0][2] == ch){
    printf("Yes");
} else {
    printf("No.");
}

if (test[1][2] == ch){
    printf("Yes");
} else {
    printf("No.");
}
```

To adress your original question, *"Is there any difference of using pointer to access two dimensional array in a function?"*. **No** because accessing arrays is based on using pointers. Example:

```
int a[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
a[5] = 23;
5[a] = 23;
*(a+5) = 23;
```

3 last lines mean the same.